# bind-attr ember helper with some text as well as variable?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In the ember docs I see this as an example
`<img {{bind-attr src=logoUrl}} alt="Logo">`

I have something like this `<a {{bind-attr href=my_url}}></a>` however, I need  a `#` in front of the `my_url` variable. I need the html to come out like this

Assume my_url has value of: section_products

So the html should be `<a href="#section_products"></a>` but the current html will be like this `<a href="section_products"></a>` ... so how can I add text in-front of variables in handlebars?

Comment: wouldn't that link with a hash collide with your route links?

Comment: If he's using location.  If you aren't using location, you'll just want to do a computed property that tacks the # on to the string and bind to that property instead.

Comment: my route links look like /#/my_route_links, this would be like "/#section_products"

Comment: If you don't need two way data binding, you can replace `<a {{bind-attr href=my_url}}></a>` with `<a href="#{{unbound my_url}}"></a>`.

Comment: ^ put that as an answer so I can accept it.